# How to Lock the send bar at the bottom in React and Tailwindcss, disable scroll below the send bar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am having difficulties locking the **send message object** at the bottom of the screen, so that the scroll effect doesn't go beyond ( downwards past )the **send message object**, as indicated in the below image.
I used React and tailwindcss

[Chat bar scroll bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgAI7.png)

Here is the Chat.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Message from './Message';
import SendMessage from './SendMessage';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { query, collection, orderBy, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';

const style = {
  main: `flex flex-col p-[10px]`,
};

const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const scroll = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'messages'), orderBy('timestamp'));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      let messages = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        messages.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setMessages(messages);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <main className={style.main}>
        {messages &&
          messages.map((message) => (
            <Message key={message.id} message={message} />
          ))}
      </main>
      {/* Send Message Compoenent */}
      <SendMessage scroll={scroll} />
      <span ref={scroll}></span>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

And here is a SendMessage.jsx code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {auth, db} from '../firebase'
import {addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp} from 'firebase/firestore'

const style = {
  form: `h-14 w-full max-w-[728px]  flex text-xl absolute bottom-0`,
  input: `w-full text-xl p-3 bg-gray-900 text-white outline-none border-none`,
  button: `w-[20%] bg-green-500`,
};

const SendMessage = ({scroll}) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (input === '') {
        alert('Please enter a valid message')
        return
    }
    const {uid, displayName} = auth.currentUser
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'messages'), {
        text: input,
        name: displayName,
        uid,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp()
    })
    setInput('')
    scroll.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={sendMessage} className={style.form}>
      <input
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        className={style.input}
        type='text'
        placeholder='Message'
      />
      <button className={style.button} type='submit'>
        Send
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SendMessage;
```